# Is It possible to Inject Customer Attributes to wsdl.xml file dynamically in Magento?

Tags: magento-enterprise, xml, php-5.4, wsdl

I'm trying to develop `Custom Module Magento V2 API` with dynamic Elements. So for that I have written statically it's working fine. Now I need to change it dynamically

here is the question?

**Normal Magento V2 API wsdl.xml file like below format**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
             xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
    <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
            <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            <complexType name="helloHellomultiCreateAddEntity"> 
                <all>
                    <element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" />
                    <element name="description" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                </all>
            </complexType>
        </schema>
    </types>
    <message name="helloHellomultiCreateRequest">
         <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
         <part name="filters" type="xsd:filters" />
     </message>
    <message name="helloHellomultiCreateResponse">
        <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="data" type="typens:helloHellomultiCreateEntity" />
    </message>
    <portType name="{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
        <operation name="helloHellomultiCreate">
            <documentation>Add Record</documentation>
            <input message="typens:helloHellomultiCreateRequest" />
            <output message="typens:helloHellomultiCreateResponse" />
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding" type="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
        <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />

        <operation name="helloHellomultiCreate">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:{{var wsdl.handler}}Action" />
            <input>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </output>
        </operation>

    </binding>
    <service name="{{var wsdl.name}}Service">
        <port name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Port" binding="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding">
            <soap:address location="{{var wsdl.url}}" />
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

**Required Magento V2 API wsdl.xml file need to change complexType as below**

```
<complexType name="helloHellomultiCreateAddEntity">
                <all>
                    <?php
                            Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getAttributes();
                            foreach($customer as $id => $key){ ?>
                            <element name="<?php echo $key ?>" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" />
                    <?php } ?>
                </all>
            </complexType>
```

**Is it possible to write PHP code in .xml file? for dynamic magento attributes as elements.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot write php code in the wsdl files.
But you can make your type `helloHellomultiCreateAddEntity` support an array of key-value pairs and you can send the attribute codes and values.
You can see an example in the `wsdl.xml` from the catalog module.
Search for the type `catalogProductReturnEntity`.
You will find this line

```
<element name="additional_attributes" type="typens:associativeArray" minOccurs="0"/>
```

You need to do something similar.

Comment: from type `catalogProductReturnEntity` i have found on 76th line as you said `<element name="additional_attributes" type="typens:associativeArray" minOccurs="0"/>`. How to know the list of key-value pairs?

Comment: you don't. you will also have to add an api method that retrieves all the customer attributes.

Comment: I could not figure out. So please explain with example? If possible

Comment: see how the `catalogProductListOfAdditionalAttributes` operation works from the same catalog wsdl.xml. this one retrieves the attributes of the product. Do something similar for customer attributes.

Comment: @Marius how to assign api method return array(which retrieves customer attributes) to parameter array